# VB .NET fast line graph shows large empty space on left and right of plotted data

Tags: .net, vb.net, graph

In the example shown, there is 150 x-axis points of unwanted space on left and right the 150 points of plotted data (middle).  Only 1/3 of the graph is used.

I plot 150 points for each of the 24 functions (ie. horizontal lines) but graph x-axis is 450 points wide and there's 150 empty x-axis points on left and right of the plotted 150 points.

Goal is to use all of x-axis to show the 150 plot points.

I've tried setting AxisX.IntervalAutoMode. to fixed and variable, but that only changes the x-axis shown numbers and not the plotted data.

[image]

Here's the subroutine that plots........

```
' Erase previous chart:
if IS_CHART_PER_FREQ
    For f = first_freq_index to end_freq_index                                          '''''''''''   F R E Q   R A N G E   '''''''''''''''''''
        Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series( present_series_name & "_I" & f ).Points.clear()   
        Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series( present_series_name & "_Q" & f ).Points.clear()   
    next
End If


. . .

   ' Plot all the points in Zoom window for a graph in multiple or scatterframe mode.
Sub plot_zoom_samples( initial_zoom_index, final_zoom_index )
    dim zoom_sample_index as integer
    dim zoom_freq_index as integer
    dim sample_X as integer

    IF present_graph_mode = "SCATTER OF MULTIPLE FRAMES"
        ' For each frame of a multiple frame mode window:
        for zoom_sample_index = initial_zoom_index to final_zoom_index
            sample_X = graph_sample_X( zoom_sample_index )
            ' For scatter graph, plot point's x,y is I,Q:
            Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series( present_series_name & "_I" & zoom_freq_index).Points.AddXY( graph_sample_I( zoom_sample_index  ), 
                                                                                                        graph_sample_Q( zoom_sample_index  ))
            zoom_freq_index += 1
            ' Wraparound after frame's set of freqs:   ie. Done with all frame's freqs?
            if zoom_freq_index = std.freqs_per_frame 
                zoom_freq_index = 0                 ' first freq of next frame
            End If
            ' Track X-axis min and max, for display of X-axis spread:
            IF sample_X < minimum_sample_X
                minimum_sample_X = sample_X
            End If
            IF sample_X > maximum_sample_X
                maximum_sample_X = sample_X
            End If
        next
    ELSE       ' NON-SCATTER, IE. MULTIPLE FRAME MODE:
        ' For each frame of a multiple frame mode window:
        for zoom_sample_index = initial_zoom_index to final_zoom_index
            sample_X = graph_sample_X( zoom_sample_index )
            ' Plot sample for each freq at same x-axis sample point:
            ' For all graphs other than scatter, their is I plot point and Q plot point, both: x,y is sampling index (ie. frame index), I | Q:
            Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series( present_series_name & "_I" & zoom_freq_index).Points.AddXY( sample_X, graph_sample_I( zoom_sample_index  ))
            Me.Chart_antenna_window.Series( present_series_name & "_Q" & zoom_freq_index).Points.AddXY( sample_X, graph_sample_Q( zoom_sample_index  ))
            zoom_freq_index += 1
            ' Wraparound after frame's set of freqs:   ie. Done with all frame's freqs?
            if zoom_freq_index = std.freqs_per_frame 
                zoom_freq_index = 0                 ' first freq of next frame
            End If
            ' Track X-axis min and max, for display of X-axis spread:
            IF sample_X < minimum_sample_X
                minimum_sample_X = sample_X
            End If
            IF sample_X > maximum_sample_X
                maximum_sample_X = sample_X
            End If
        next
    END IF
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to do this:...

Me.Chart_antenna_window.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Maximum = maximum_sample_X
Me.Chart_antenna_window.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Minimum = minimum_sample_X